# jquery: live wrapper for on

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapper, live

We have an very old jquery code in my js project, We are preparing to migrate to jquery 3, but I have problems writing a wrapper for live/on:

```
(function($)
{ 
    $.fn.click = function(f)
    {
        this.on('click', f);
        return this;
    };
    $.fn.live = function(e, f)
    {
        $(document).on(e, this, f);
        return this;
    };  
}(jQuery));
```

click event works fine but the live event attaches to another selectors that I didn't choose, example here: https://jsfiddle.net/yvrbko35/

when you click in the first A, the SPAN LIVE CODE is executed

Comment: You code works fine, the live event is triggered as shown in console.

Comment: `but the live event attaches to another selectors that I didn't choose` Which other selectors?

Comment: when you click in the first A the SPAN LIVE CODE is executed

Comment: The logic is flawed because you're attempting to call a function on an empty jQuery object. The `span` doesn't exist, hence `this` within `$.fn.live()` is empty.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan with this logic the `$(document).on` has no sense neither

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you are right about it, the selector is empty and I can't use it like this, I need to get the selector used and send it like text, I need to change jquery core :_D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, clicking the #a1 also triggers the span on click, which you don't want.

You could check wether the target matches the selector of the event you don't want to execute on span and only execute when it doesn't match.

https://jsfiddle.net/q5ydLjj9/

```
$('span').live('click', function(e)
{
  if (!$(e.target).is('#a1'))
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('live click');      
   } 
  });
```

Comment: I would like to do a wrapper for all cases, not for preventing specific selector

Answer (score 0):

Editing the Jquery Core to get "selector":

in this function:

`init = jQuery.fn.init`

at first:

`this.selector = selector;`

inside of this if:

`if ( typeof selector === "string" )`

at this position:

```
        // HANDLE: $(expr, $(...))
        } else if ( !context || context.jquery ) {
            var r = ( context || root ).find( selector );
            r.selector = selector;
            return r;

        // HANDLE: $(expr, context)
        // (which is just equivalent to: $(context).find(expr)
        }
        else
        {
            var r = this.constructor( context ).find( selector );
            r.selector = selector;
            return r;
        }
```

edit the objects to add selector attribute to the return object

the live wrapper's code like this:

```
$.fn.live = function(e, f)
{   
    $(document).on(e, this.selector, f);

    return this;
};
```